# Building .so with recursive function in it

Tags: assembly, shared-libraries, x86-64, gnu, dynamic-linking

During working on some project, I faced the issue that I can't build so library. I have got the error like: *relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol '' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC*
Eventually I managed to find the root cause. And it was recursive function in the library. For example, I have the following well know example:

```
.section .text
.globl factorial
.type  factorial,STT_FUNC
factorial:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp,%rbp

    mov 16(%rbp),%rax
    cmp $1,%rax
    je end_factorial
    dec %rax
    push %rax  #this is how we pass the argument to function
    call factorial
    pop %rbx
    inc %rbx
    imul %rbx,%rax
end_factorial:
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Now, let's try to build the shared library:

```
as  -g -o fact.o fact.s
ld -shared fact.o -o libfact.so
ld: fact.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `factorial' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

If I wrap the factorial function, like this:

```
.section .text
.globl fact
.type  fact,STT_FUNC
fact:
factorial:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp,%rbp

    mov 16(%rbp),%rax
    cmp $1,%rax
    je end_factorial
    dec %rax
    push %rax  #this is how we pass the argument to function
    call factorial
    pop %rbx
    inc %rbx
    imul %rbx,%rax
end_factorial:
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

I can build the so library with no errors.

---

The question is: why do I get an error while building shared library that contains recursive function?
P.S. The static linking works fine in that case. 
Thanks!

Comment: For global symbols, you need to use either the PLT or the GOT, that is `call factorial@PLT` or `call *factorial@GOTPCREL(%rip)`. If you wish, you can do the wrapping in reverse of course so you can keep the public `factorial` symbol and use some local for the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`factorial` is a global label, so it can be subject to **symbol interposition**.  See [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/).  (Also, [an example of interposing `malloc` with LD_PRELOAD](http://jayconrod.com/posts/23/tutorial-function-interposition-in-linux), and some [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/gejgf.html)).

**When making a shared library, the target of the `call factorial` instruction is not assumed to be the `factorial:` label defined in the same file**.  That's *because* you used `.globl factorial`.

As Jester points out, you should define a separate local label for the `call` target so you can keep the global `factorial` name.

You can make a simpler "helper" function that uses its own custom calling convention and doesn't make stack frames with `%rbp` for the recursive part, if you want.  (But taking an arg on the stack is already non-standard for x86-64).

---

You *could* call through the PLT or memory-indirect through the GOT, but don't do that; you don't want the extra overhead on each `call`, and you don't want symbol interposition to replace your non-standard-calling-convention implementation with a normal one that passes the first integer arg in `%rdi`.

Speaking of which, passing an arg on the stack is slow.  You do need to save/restore something, unless you [rewrite the recursion to be tail-recursive, like `factorial_helper(accumulator*n, n-1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518882/how-exactly-does-tail-recursion-work).  But you don't also need to make a stack frame with `%rbp` every time.

You're not maintaining 16-byte stack alignment before the `call`, but you don't need that when calling your own private functions that don't care about that.

Of course, if you care about performance at all, you wouldn't use a recursive implementation in the first place, because the only reason to do that for `factorial` is as a learning exercise.  Rewriting to tail-recursive allows you ([or the compiler if writing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518882/how-exactly-does-tail-recursion-work)) to turn the `call` / `ret` into a `jmp`, which of course becomes a loop.

---

Related: [What are good examples that actually motivate the study of recursion?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/what-are-good-examples-that-actually-motivate-the-study-of-recursion/4361#4361).  A binary tree traversal, or the Ackermann function, are easier to implement recursively than iteratively, but `factorial` or Fibonacci are harder (and in the case of Fibonacci, *much* slower).

Comment: As a side note, GCC8 should know to optimize recursive calls to not use PLT (thanks to [PR56727](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56727)).

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is clear. Factorial was just an example. Also you said about 16 byte stack alignment. I thought that it should be 8 byte alignment on x86-64, isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewBolotov: if this answers your question, click the "accept" checkmark under the up/down vote arrows. :)