# how to get the entry point of an assembly program with 2 files

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

I'm linking a program with 2 assembly files.

How can I force the program to put some code of the first file before some code of the second file (in this pseudocode snippet, I want the instructions to be called from 0 to 5)?

```
#file a
do_this:
   inst 1
   inst 2

do_that:
   inst 3
   inst 4

#file b
no_no_do_this_first:
   inst 0

and_do_this_finally:
   inst 5
```

using sections?

Is there another way?

Ok, after reading some more I found that as I'm compiling with C, this answer might apply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584294/10734452

But currently my files are:
`crt0_generic` ,
`crt0_customerA`

or
`crt0_generic` ,
`crt0_customerB`

and I need some function of the crt0_generic to be called first

Comment: What environment? For non-flat binaries you typically have an entry point specified via label so it does not matter what comes first.

Comment: how to define this label?
(i'm cross compiling for riscv)

Comment: It's normally called `_start` on unix-like systems. Your linker should have complained if it was missing.

Comment: i edited my question because It cannot be as generic as I wanted, as I'm compiling assembly with C

Comment: If I want the 'reset' label to be called before the '_start' label, how could I do?

Comment: You can tell the linker to use your `reset` as entry point but then make sure you transfer control to `_start` after you are done (with the proper register and stack state).

Comment: The above only applies if you are creating normal user mode program running under an OS with a standard loader of course. If you are trying to do bare metal, with stuff having to be put in specific places you likely need linker scripts.