# Making a terminal in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I run this c snippet, it outputs something really random every time, and then segfaults...
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse(void) {
  int i = 0;
  int system(const char *command);
  char line[1024];
  scanf("%[^\n]", line);
  system(line);
  do {
    line[i] = "\0";
    i++;
  } while (i != 1024);
  parse();
}

int main(void) {
  parse();
  return 0;
}
```

What I expected was a prompt, and when any shell command is entered (I used pwd for my testing), the output of the command prints and the prompt returns. And this is what actually happened:

Output:

```
> pwd
/home/runner/c-test
sh: 1: �: not found
sh: 1: : not found
sh: 1: ׀: not found
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: First of all, why do you provide your own prototype for the `system` function, instead of using the one provided by `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Secondly, `line[i]` is a single character, a single `char`. `"\0"` is a null.terminated string, an array of two elements (both being the null-terminator) which decays to a pointer to its first element. Why do you assign this pointer to the character `line[i]`? Doesn't the compiler issue a warning about this? Then you need to enable more warnings, and treat them as errors.

Comment: Thirdly, why are you using recursion instead of a loop?

Comment: Fourthly, you don't output any prompt, so why do you expect one?

Comment: And you're not really making a terminal, but rather a program that works somewhat similar to a *shell*.

Comment: you call yourself - your stack consumption will increase with every iteration

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/wmPB3ZGNQ

Comment: @0___________ it is tail recursion, which gets optimized to a loop anyway. Not saying it is good, but it will not consume more stack memory.

Comment: @Tenobaal no it will not,as it has to add stack space for local variables on every call https://godbolt.org/z/T3Peqh45n  Stack consumption will grow

Comment: @0___________ gcc does, I tried it. The lifetime of the local variables values end all end with the recursive call. "-foptimize-sibling-calls
Optimize sibling and tail recursive calls. Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os." from the gcc docs

Comment: Also it it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518882/how-exactly-does-tail-recursion-work)

Comment: @Tenobaal gcc does not in this case. This case can't be tail optimized out. see my link.

Comment: @0___________ I see... can you explain why?

Comment: @Tenobaal because it has to keep copy of the local variables on every call.

Comment: @0___________ but why? They are not needed anymore at the point of the recursive call, which should allow the compiler to optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Print prompt
2. Do not use scanf
3. Use static storage duration buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int parse(void) 
{
  static char line[1024];
  while(1)
  {
      printf(">>>");
      if(!fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) return 1;
      system(line);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  parse();
}
```

https://www.onlinegdb.com/wmPB3ZGNQ

[image]

Comment: Are you really proposing a solution using recursion?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Does not matter as recurson will be optimized out  https://godbolt.org/z/qjqEnrnYT

Comment: This optimization is just a random effect, you teach bad habits. -- Oh, and you do not explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your crash is most likely explained by the following:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", line);
```

means keep reading until there is a newline in the input stream. So once it completes the next character in the input stream is a newline.

The next time you do

```
scanf("%[^\n]", line);
```

that newline is still the first character, so the `scanf` will return without waiting for the user to type any input.

Since you are doing recursion this will happen again and again and again.... Then most likely the system crashes due to stack overflow after a while.

Solution: Read that newline from the input stream before calling `scanf` again.

Besides that you should:

- Remove `int system(const char *command);`
- Put a maximum field width on `scanf`
- Check the return value of `scanf`
- Change `"\0"` to `'\0'` (or delete the whole do-while loop as you don't need it)
- Use a `while(1) { ... }` loop instead of recursive calls

Comment: Solution: do not use `scanf` with an unbounded buffer like that.

Comment: @Dúthomhas The real solution would be to delete all the code and do it completely different. But the point of this answer is to explain why OPs code behaves the way it does. I do not intend to rewrite OPs code. We are not a free coding service